# SceneBuilder with mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, scenebuilder

please advise me on the two described below problems.

1. I have form in `fxml(TextFields)` for add information to the  database.But it does not work ( the data doesnot record to the database)
   Code:

   ```
   String str="insert into contacts values(?,?,?,?,?)";
   con = javaconectDB.ConectDB(); //загрузка базы
   prep = con.prepareStatement(str);

   prep.setString(1, edName.getText());
   prep.setString(2, edLn.getText());
   prep.setString(3, edE.getText());
   prep.setString(4, edP.getText());
   prep.executeQuery();
   db.getData().add(new aWork(edName.getText(), edLn.getText(),edE.getText(),edP.getText()));
   edName.setText(null);edLn.setText(null);
   edE.setText(null);edP.setText(null);
   ```

   }
   Where "db" is java class, which is reading DB from mysql, getData() - is Getter.
2. ComboBox fxml is NOT JComboBox

   ```
    String sql="SELECT NAME FirstName*from contacts";
    javaconectDB jc=new javaconectDB();
     con=javaconectDB.ConectDB();
     prep=con.prepareStatement("SELECT Phone FROM contacts");
     ResultSet   rs=prep.executeQuery();
     while (rs.next()){
     String name=rs.getString("Phone");
     cmbCarrera."..."(name);
   ```

I want similar to this code:
          cmbCarrera.addItems(name);

but if I use ComboBox fxml, I havn't code addItems, I have only addEventHandler

What should i do or what is wrong in the code ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the Stacktrace?

Comment: Stacktrace catch this code
   }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERRORRRR!!!");
        }}

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: I have tried, but it hasn't helped

Comment: Your problem now is another one. Please don't catch the exception without managing the error. Print the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate data you need `executeUpdate()` rather than `executeQuery()`.

**ExecuteUpdate**:

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

**ExecuteQuery** is used for all the statements that return a ResultSet.